# PowerBI Desktop - Identifying Common Items that belongs to the Selected Values in a column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to do some analytics on PowerBI. I am struck at this logic, where I am trying to Identify the common items with in the group and not common items with in the group.

For Example,

```
Group Name  Contact
GroupA      Rock 
GroupA      Eddy
GroupA      Brown
GroupB      Rock 
GroupB      Katie
GroupC      Eddy
GroupC      Brown
GroupC      Katie
```

If I select GroupA and GroupB then I want to output the Common Items as 1 and not common Items as 3.

The Common Item is Rock
The Not Common Items are Eddy, Brown & Katie.( I am looking to get this as part of my output visual as well)

How can we do this in PowerBI which works dynamically when we select multiple groups (more than 2 as well)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by checking if the number of groups the `Contact` appears in is the same as the number of groups that you have selected:

```
Common = IF(COUNTROWS(VALUES(Groups[Group Name])) =
               COUNTROWS(CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Groups[Group Name]),
                                     ALLSELECTED(Groups))),
               "Common", "Not Common")
```

Then you can use these labels inside a second measure to get the count:

```
Intersect = IF([Common] = "Common",
               CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Groups[Contact]), 
                         FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Groups[Contact]), [Common] = "Common")),
               CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Groups[Contact]),
                         FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Groups[Contact]), [Common] = "Not Common")))
```

You can then set up a table or matrix using `Contact` and the new measure `Intersect` along with a slicer on `Group Name`.

[image: Contact Table]